# Looking for a substitute for onions

Tags: substitutions, onions

I love onions, but as an IBS sufferer, I find that it is one of my trigger foods and gives me diarrhea. Is there anything that I can put in recipes as a substitute?

Comment: I think people use Asofoetida to help with IBS, look at it ... or use leaks (milder than onions) or french échalottes (in smaller quantities)

Comment: There are a couple of very similar questions out there already (see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44800/whats-a-good-substitute-of-onion-for-someone-with-an-onion-allergy?rq=1, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/substitute-for-onions-and-garlic?rq=1) and the top answers for both suggest the same spice as a solution.