# How to preserve eggplants/brinjals?

Tags: vegetables, food-preservation, eggplant

How can eggplant be preserved? I would like to preserve it for a month or more, if possible.

Comment: not an eggplant … Brinjal

Comment: Spynet: http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-brinjal-and-eggplant

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius sorry sir is there any way to protect a month….

Comment: Your comment on the answer suggests you're looking for a means of preservation that doesn't involve pickling or extensive preparation.  Can you clarify your question?  It may simply not be possible to keep a whole eggplant for a month unless you keep it on the plant.

Comment: if i keep in plant will be fully grow and it will became a seed of the egg plant sir

Answer (score 1):

There's a Sicilian preservation of eggplant called [Melanzane Sott’Olio](http://www.cookbookarchaeology.com/?p=1657).  It's similar to giardiniera, but after pickling, you pack it in oil.

Because of the botulism risk of putting garlic in oil, it's considered risky for long-term storage (more than a week, and that's refrigerated), even though it was used in Sicily for generations.  You might be able to [replace the garlic](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2596/67) with something safer, or omit it entirely.

Comment: is there alternate idea or machanisum i am looking for …..